# Is it possible to have 2 classes in a element?

Tags: html, css, font-awesome

Sorry if you didnt understand the title properly.  I have a font awesome icon, which links my social media. I want each icon to have a different color, ive managed to do change the color for **all** of  them, but thats not the case.

This is the icon: `<i class="fab fa-twitch fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i>`
I was wondering how to have **2** classes, like `<i class="purple" class="fab fa-twitch fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i>` Any idea on how to do this?

Also, my css is:

`.purple { color: purple;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. just separate them with a space. like this: `class="fab fa-twitch fa-2x purple"`. 
And BTW `fab fa-twitch fa-2x` are 3 different classes (`fab`,`fa-twitch` and `fa-2x`).

Answer (score 3):

You just need only 1 class attribute (you can't have more). Put all classes you need inside

```
<i class="fab fa-twitch fa-2x purple" aria-hidden="true"></i>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can put the `purple` class inside the `class=` with the other classes:

```html
<i class="fab fa-twitch fa-2x purple" aria-hidden="true"></i>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can have a multitude of classes in the class attribute, it only needs and should only be called once, you simply put a space between the classes within the class attribute. Your CSS looks good.

See the following link for more info on HTML related class attribute: [HTML Class Attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/class)

```
<i class="purple fab fa-twitch fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
```